# Not able to extract an <p> tag using web scraping. The result is returning null

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's my script:

```
url = "https://www.walmart.com.mx/productos?Ntt=notebook"
agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=agent)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
print(soup)
urls = []
for p_tag in soup.findAll('p'):
    urls.append = p_tag
print(urls);
```

The urls list is returning null.

Printing the request returns this file, but in this file I checked it isn't equal to the 
actual file on the browser console. Can anyone Help I`m an beginner on the subject.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible"/><meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no,shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport"/><meta content="#000000" name="theme-color"/><script type="text/javascript">(function(){(function(){function a(){if(void 0===b.dialogArguments)return navigator.cookieEnabled;document.cookie="__dTCookie=1";var a=-1!==document.cookie.indexOf("__dTCookie");document.cookie="__dTCookie=1; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";return a}if(window.dT_)window.console&&window.console.log("Duplicate agent injection detected, turning off redundant initConfig.");else{var b="undefined"!==typeof window?window:self;a()&&(window.dT_||(window.dT_={cfg:"domain=walmart.com.mx|reportUrl=/rb_3770e195-dd69-4828-8cae-1067062e79aa|app=8f56071731344bd0|ssc=1|featureHash=A27SVfjqrux|srsr=25000|rdnt=1|uxrgce=1|bp=2|srms=1,1,,,|uxrgcm=100,25,300,3;100,25,300,3|dpvc=1|lastModification=1572550684266|dtVersion=10175190917092722|tp=500,50,0,1|uxdcw=1500|agentUri=/ruxitagentjs_A27SVfjqrux_10175190917092722.js|auto=1|domain=walmart.com.mx|rid=RID_-233466361|rpid=-741352723|app=8f56071731344bd0",iCE:a}))}})();}).call(this);(function(){(function(){function Jb(){return ta?new ta:ua?new ua("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0"):d.XMLHttpRequest?new d.XMLHttpRequest:new d.ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")}function Kb(){ua=ta=void 0}function t(){var a=0;try{a=d.performance.timing.navigationStart+Math.floor(d.performance.now())}catch(b){}return 0>=a||isNaN(a)||!isFinite(a)?(new Date).getTime():a}function Y(a,b){function c(){delete la[g];a.apply(this,arguments)}for(var e=[],I=2;I<arguments.length;I++)e[I-2]=arguments[I];var g;"apply"in va?g=va.apply(d,[c,b].concat(e)):g=va(c,b);la[g]=!0;return g}function Za(a){delete la[a];"apply"in Z?Z.call(d,a):Z(a)}function k(a){for(var b=[],c=1;c<arguments.length;c++)b[c-1]=arguments[c];a.push.apply(a,b)}function $a(a){k(aa,a)}function Lb(a){for(var b=aa.length;b--;)if(aa[b]===a){aa.splice(b,1);break}}function Mb(){return aa}function Nb(a,b){return ab(a,b)}function Ob(a,b){a=new Pb([a],{type:b});return Qb(a)}function Rb(a,b){return bb?new bb(a,b):void 0}function Sb(a){"function"===typeof a&&k(cb,a)}function Tb(){return cb}
function Ub(){return Da}function db(a){return function(){for(var b=[],c=0;c<arguments.length;c++)b[c]=arguments[c];if("number"!==typeof b[0]||!la[b[0]])try{return a.apply(this,b)}catch(e){return a(b[0])}}}function Vb(){ma&&(d.clearTimeout=Z,d.clearInterval=Ea,ma=!1)}function ba(a,b){return isNaN(a)||isNaN(b)?0:Math.floor(Math.random()*(b-a+1))+a}function u(a,b){return parseInt(a,b||10)}function p(a,b,c){void 0===c&&(c=0);var e=-1;b&&a&&a.indexOf&&(e=a.indexOf(b,c));return e}function eb(a){return document.getElementsByTagName(a)}
function fb(a){var b=a.length;if("number"===typeof b)a=b;else{for(var b=0,c=2048;a[c-1];)b=c,c+=c;for(var e=7;1<c-b;)e=(c+b)/2,a[e-1]?b=e:c=e;a=a[e]?c:b}return a}function Wb(a){a=encodeURIComponent(a);var b=[];if(a)for(var c=0;c<a.length;c++){var e=a.charAt(c);k(b,Xb[e]||e)}return b.join("")}function O(a){if(!a)return"";var b=d.crypto||d.msCrypto;if(b){var c=new Int8Array(a);b.getRandomValues(c)}else for(c=[],b=0;b<a;b++)c.push(ba(0,32));a=[];for(b=0;b<c.length;b++){var e=Math.abs(c[b]%32);a.push(String.fromCharCode(e+
(9>=e?48:55)))}return a.join("")}function gb(){return!(!d.console||!d.console.log)}function Yb(){try{Zb.apply(d.parent,arguments)}catch(a){}}function $b(){try{ac.apply(d.top,arguments)}catch(a){}}function bc(a){var b=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);try{cc.apply(a,b)}catch(c){}}function dc(a){var b=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);try{ec.apply(a,b)}catch(c){}}function z(){return d.dT_}function fc(){return A}function gc(){return hb}function hc(){return ib}function ic(){return wa}function jb(){return"dtAdk"}
function jc(){return ca}function kb(a){-1<d.dT_.io(a,"^")&&(a=a.split("^^").join("^"),a=a.split("^dq").join('"'),a=a.split("^rb").join(">"),a=a.split("^lb").join("<"),a=a.split("^p").join("|"),a=a.split("^e").join("="),a=a.split("^s").join(";"),a=a.split("^c").join(","),a=a.split("^bs").join("\\"));return a}function kc(){return P}function lc(a){P=a}function lb(a){var b=d.dT_,c=b.scv("rid"),b=b.scv("rpid");c&&(a.rid=c);b&&(a.rpid=b)}function mb(a){if(a.xb){a=kb(a.xb);try{P=new RegExp(a)}catch(b){}}}
function nb(a){var b={};a=a.split("|");for(var c=0;c<a.length;c++){var e=a[c].split("=");2===e.length&&(b[e[0]]=decodeURIComponent(e[1].replace(/\+/g," ")))}return b}function Fa(){var a=l("csu");return(a.indexOf("dbg")===a.length-3?a.substr(0,a.length-3):a)+"_"+l("app")+"_Store"}function xa(a,b,c){b=b||{};a=a.split("|");for(var e=0;e<a.length;e++){var d=a[e],g=p(a[e],"=");-1===g?b[d]="1":(d=a[e].substring(0,g),b[d]=a[e].substring(g+1,a[e].length))}!c&&(c=b,a=c.spc)&&(e=document.createElement("textarea"),e.innerHTML=a,c.spc=e.value);return b}function Q(a){return a in f?f[a]:ya[a]}function m(a){a=Q(a);return"false"===a||"0"===a?!1:!!a}function J(a){var b=u(Q(a));isNaN(b)&&(b=ya[a]);return b}function l(a){return String(Q(a)||"")}function mc(a,b){f[a]=b}function ob(a){return f=a}function pb(a){var b=location.hostname;return b&&a?b===a||-1!==b.indexOf("."+a,b.length-("."+a).length):!0}function Ga(a){f[a]=0>p(f[a],"#"+a.toUpperCase())?f[a]:""}function Ha(a){var b=a.agentUri;b&&-1<p(b,"_")&&(b=/([a-zA-Z]*)[0-9]{0,4}_([a-zA-Z_0-9]*)_[0-9]+/g.exec(b))&&b.length&&2<b.length&&(a.csu=b[1],a.featureHash=b[2])}function Ia(a,b){pb(f.domain||"")||(f.domainOverride=location.hostname+","+f.domain,delete f.domain);f.pVO&&(a.pVO=f.pVO);b||(a.bp=a.bp||ya.bp,1===h&&a.bp1&&(a.bp=1),a.bp2&&(a.bp=2),4!==a.bp||d.JSON||(a.bp=1))}function nc(){return f}function da(a,b){try{var c=na;c&&c.setItem(a,b)}catch(e){}}function ea(a){try{var b=na;if(b)return b.getItem(a)}catch(c){}return null}function R(a){try{var b=na;b&&b.removeItem(a)}catch(c){}}function za(a,b){if(S()&&(!z().A||qb))return a.apply(this,b||[])}function S(){return!m("coo")||m("cooO")||qb}function n(a){document.cookie=a+'="";path=/'+(l("domain")?";domain="+l("domain"):"")+"; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;"}function rb(a,b,c){var e=1,d=0;do document.cookie=a+'=""'+(b?";domain="+b:"")+";path="+c.substr(0,e)+"; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;",e=c.indexOf("/",e),d++;while(-1!==e&&5>d)}function K(a){var b=document.cookie;if(!b)return"";var c=a+"=";a=p(b,c);if(0>a)return"";for(;0<=a;)if(a&&" "!==b.charAt(a-1)&&";"!==b.charAt(a-1))a=p(b,c,a+c.length);else return c=a+c.length,a=p(b,";",a),0<=a?b.substring(c,a):b.substr(c);return""}function oc(a,b,c,e){b||0===b?(b=(""+b).replace(/[;\n\r]/g,"_"),a=a+"="+b+";path=/"+(l("domain")?";domain="+l("domain"):""),c&&(a+=";expires="+c.toUTCString()),e&&(a+=";Secure"),document.cookie=a):n(a)}function B(a,b,c,e){za(oc,[a,b,c,e])}function oa(a){var b=/^[0-9A-Za-z_=:\$\+\/\.\-\*%\|]*$/.test(a);return a&&2<a.split("$").length?!1:b}function sb(){var a=K(A);a||((a=ea(A))&&oa(a)?T(a):a="");return oa(a)?a:""}function T(a){B(A,a,void 0,m("ssc"))}function pa(a){return 32===a.length||12>=a.length?a:""}function tb(a){if(!isNaN(Number(a))){var b=u(a);if(-99<=b&&99>=b)return a}return""}function ub(a){var b={sessionId:"",b:""},c=p(a,"|"),e=a;-1!==c&&(e=a.substring(0,c));c=p(e,"$");-1!==c?(b.sessionId=pa(e.substring(c+1)),b.b=tb(e.substring(0,c))):b.sessionId=pa(e);return b}function vb(a){var b={sessionId:"",b:""};a=a.split("v"===a.charAt(0)?"_":"=");if(2<a.length&&!(a.length%2)){var c=Number(a[1]);if(isNaN(c)||3>c)return b;for(var c={},e=2;e<a.length;e++)c[a[e]]=a[e+1],e++;c.sn?b.sessionId=pa(c.sn):b.sessionId="hybrid";c.srv&&(b.b=tb(c.srv));"1"===c.ol&&(da("dtDisabled","true"),z().disabled=!0,z().A=!0)}return b}function C(a){var b=document.cookie?document.cookie.split(a+"=").length-1:0;if(1<b){var c=l("domain")||d.location.hostname,e=d.location.hostname,I=d.location.pathname,g=0,f=0;D.push(a);do{var h=e.substr(g);if(h!==c||"/"!==I){rb(a,h===c?"":h,I);var k=document.cookie?document.cookie.split(a+"=").length-1:0;k<b&&(D.push(h),b=k)}g=e.indexOf(".",g)+1;f++}while(g&&10>f&&1<b);l("domain")&&1<b&&rb(a,"",I)}}function pc(){C(ca);C(A);C(wa);C("rxvt");$a(function(a,b,c,e){0<D.length&&!b&&(a.av(e,0,"dCN",function(){return D.join(",")}),a.av(e,4,"duplicateCookieNames",function(){return D.slice()}),D=[])})}function qc(){return fa}function Aa(a,b,c,e,d){var g=document.createElement("script");g.setAttribute("src",a);b&&g.setAttribute("defer","true");c&&(g.onload=c);e&&(g.onerror=e);d&&g.setAttribute("id",d);g.setAttribute("crossorigin","anonymous");a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentElement.insertBefore(g,a)}function Ja(a,b){return Ka+"/"+(b||U)+"_"+a+"_"+(J("buildNumber")||z().version)+".js"}function Ba(a){S()?a():(v||(v=[]),k(v,a))}function rc(a){return za(a)}function sc(){for(var a=0;a<v.length;a++)Y(v[a],0);v=[];f.cooO=!0}function tc(){f.cooO=!1;n(A);n(ca);n(wa);n("dtSa");n(jb());0===h&&(n("rxVisitor"),n("rxvt"));try{var a=na;a&&(0===h&&a.removeItem("rxVisitor"),a.removeItem(A));(a=La)&&a.removeItem(Fa())}catch(b){}}function wb(a){if(a=a||sb()){var b=a.charAt(0);return"v"===b||"="===b?vb(a):ub(a)}return{sessionId:"",b:""}}function V(a){return wb(a).b}function ga(a){return wb(a).sessionId}function uc(){return q}function vc(){Ba(function(){ga()||T((0===h?-1*ba(2,21)+"$":"")+O(32));q=V()||""})}function L(a,b){try{d.localStorage&&d.localStorage.setItem(a,b)}catch(c){}}function qa(a){try{if(d.localStorage)return d.localStorage.getItem(a)}catch(b){}return null}
function ha(a){try{d.localStorage&&d.localStorage.removeItem(a)}catch(b){}}function xb(a,b){b=E(b);for(var c=!1,e=0;e<b.length;e++)b[e].frameId===fa&&(b[e].g=a,c=!0);c||k(b,{frameId:fa,g:a});ia(b)}function ia(a,b,c){if(a){var e=0===h;var d=[];for(var g=0;g<a.length;g++)if("-"!==a[g].g){0<g&&0<d.length&&k(d,"p");var f=q;f&&(k(d,f),k(d,"$"));k(d,a[g].frameId);k(d,"h");k(d,a[g].g)}e&&!d.length&&(Ma&&(M(0,!0,"a"),Na(!1)),q=V()||"",k(d,q),k(d,"$"),k(d,fa),k(d,"h-"));a=e?b||Oa():W();if(e||a)k(d,"v"),k(d,a),e="undefined"!==typeof c?c:r(),0<=e&&(k(d,"e"),k(d,e));d=d.join("")}else d="";d||0!==h||(Ma&&(M(0,!0,"a"),Na(!1)),q=V()||"",c="undefined"!==typeof c?c:r(),d=q+"$"+fa+"h-v"+(b||Oa()+(0<=c?"e"+c:"")));B(ca,d||"-",void 0,m("ssc"))}function E(a){var b=K(ca),c=[];if(b&&"-"!==b){for(var b=b.split("p"),d="",f=null,g=0;g<b.length;g++){var h=b[g],m=p(h,"h"),l=p(h,"v"),n=p(h,"e"),w=h.substring(p(h,"$")+1,m),m=-1!==l?h.substring(m+1,l):h.substring(m+1),d=d||-1!==l?-1!==n?h.substring(l+1,n):h.substring(l+
1):"",f=f||-1!==n?h.substring(n+1):null;(h=a)||(h=u(w.split("_")[0]),l=t()%Pa,l<h&&(l+=Pa),h=h+9E5>l);h&&k(c,{frameId:w,g:"-"===m?"-":u(m)})}for(g=0;g<c.length;g++)c[g].visitId=d||"",c[g].j=null!==f?u(f):-1}return c}function Oa(){return W()||M(0,!0,"c")}function W(){var a=E(!0);if(!(F()<=t())){X(!1);if(1<=a.length)return-1!==r()&&2<=J(Qa)&&a[0].j>=J(wc)?M(0,!0,"e"+a[0].j):a[0].visitId||"";(a=qa(ja))||(a=ea(ja));return a||""}return""}function X(a){var b=t(),c=yb().m;a&&(c=b);zb(b+Ab+"|"+c);Bb()}function Cb(a,b){a||(a=ba(1,1E6));var c=ga()||"";c||(c=(0===h?-1*ba(2,21)+"$":"")+O(32),T(c),c=ga(c)||"");a=""+a;for(var d=a.length,f=[],g=0;g<c.length;g++)f[g]=String.fromCharCode(65+Math.abs((c.charCodeAt(g)^a.charCodeAt(g%d))%26));c=f.join("");for(a=0;a<Ra.length;a++)Ra[a](c,N,b);return c}function Sa(a){var b=E(!1),c=2<=J(Qa)?0:-1;ia(b,a,c);Ta(ja,a);L(Ua,String(c));X(!0)}function M(a,b,c){b&&(N=!0);a=Cb(t(),c);Sa(a);return a}function xc(a){Ra.push(a)}function Bb(){Va&&Za(Va);Va=Y(Db,F()-t())}function Db(){if(F()<=t()&&S()){var a=t(),a=Cb(a,"t"+(a-F()));Sa(a);return!0}Ba(Bb);return!1}function zb(a){B("rxvt",a,void 0,m("ssc"));Ta("rxvt",a)}function Ta(a,b){m("dpvc")||m("pVO")?(da(a,b),ha(a)):(L(a,b),R(a))}function Eb(){var a=K("rxvt");a||(a=qa("rxvt")||"")||(a=ea("rxvt")||"");return a}function Fb(){var a=W()||"";Ta(ja,a);a=Eb();zb(a)}function yb(){var a={v:0,m:0},b=Eb();if(b)try{var c=b.split("|");2===c.length&&(a.v=parseInt(c[0],10),a.m=parseInt(c[1],10))}catch(e){}return a}function F(){var a=yb();return Math.min(a.v,a.m+Gb)}function yc(a){Ab=a}function Na(a){void 0===a&&(a=!0);Ma=a}function zc(){var a=N;N=!1;return a}function Ac(){Db()||X(!1)}function Bc(){if(0===h&&-1!==r()&&2<=J(Qa)){var a=E(!1),b=r()+1;ia(a,"",b);L(Ua,String(b))}}function r(){var a=E(!0);if(1<=a.length&&!isNaN(a[0].j))return a[0].j;a=qa(Ua)||"";a=u(a);return isNaN(a)?-1:a}function Wa(){var a=K("rxVisitor");if(!a||a.length&&a.length!==Xa)a=qa("rxVisitor")||ea("rxVisitor"),a&&a.length===Xa||(Hb=!0,a=t()+"",a+=O(Xa-a.length));var b=a;if(m("dpvc")||m("pVO"))da("rxVisitor",b);else{var c=new Date;c.setFullYear(c.getFullYear()+2);L("rxVisitor",b)}B("rxVisitor",b,c,m("ssc"));return a}function Cc(){return Hb}function Dc(a){var b=K("rxVisitor");n("rxVisitor");R("rxVisitor");ha("rxVisitor");B("rxVisitor",b);f.pVO=!0;a&&L(Ya,"1");Fb()}function Ec(){ha(Ya);m("pVO")&&(f.pVO=!1,Wa());Fb()}function Fc(){var a=d.dT_;d.dT_={version:"10175190917092722",cfg:a?a.cfg:"",iCE:a?a.iCE:function(){return navigator.cookieEnabled},ica:1,disabled:!1,A:!1,gx:Jb,cx:Kb,mp:Yb,mtp:$b,mi:bc,mw:dc,gAST:Ub,ww:Rb,stu:Ob,nw:t,apush:k,st:Y,si:Nb,aBPSL:$a,rBPSL:Lb,gBPSL:Mb,aBPSCC:Sb,gBPSCC:Tb,buildType:0===h?"dynatrace":"appmon",gSSV:ea,sSSV:da,rSSV:R,rvl:ha,pn:u,iVSC:oa,p3SC:vb,pLSC:ub,io:p,dC:n,sC:B,esc:Wb,gSId:V,gDtc:ga,gSC:sb,sSC:T,gC:K,cRN:ba,cRS:O,gEL:fb,gEBTN:eb,gSCN:fc,gPCHN:gc,gRHN:hc,gPCCN:jc,gLCN:ic,gMSIDCN:jb,cfgO:nc,pCfg:nb,pCSAA:xa,cFHFAU:Ha,sCD:Ia,bcv:m,ncv:J,scv:l,stcv:mc,rplC:ob,cLSCK:Fa,gFId:qc,gBAU:Ja,iS:Aa,eWE:Ba,oEIE:rc,oEIEWA:za,eA:sc,dA:tc,gcSId:uc,iNV:Cc,gVID:Wa,dPV:Dc,ePV:Ec,sVIdUP:Na,sVTT:yc,sVID:Sa,rVID:W,gVI:Oa,gNVId:M,gARnVF:zc,cAUV:Ac,uVT:X,aNVL:xc,gPC:E,cPC:xb,sPC:ia,clB:Vb,ct:Za,aRI:lb,iXB:mb,gXBR:kc,sXBR:lc,de:kb,cCL:gb,gEC:r,iEC:Bc}}var G=window;if(!G.dT_||!G.dT_.cfg||"string"!=typeof G.dT_.cfg||G.dT_.initialized)G.console&&G.console.log("Initconfig not found or agent already initialized! This is an injection issue.");else if(!(navigator.userAgent&&0<=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("RuxitSynthetic"))){var d="undefined"!==typeof window?window:self,ta,ua,aa,cb=[],Da,La,na,la={},Xb=new(function(){return function(){this["!"]="%21";this["~"]="%7E";this["*"]="%2A";this["("]="%28";this[")"]="%29";this["'"]="%27";this.$="%24";this[";"]="%3B";this[","]="%2C"}}()),va,ab,cc=d.postMessage,bb=d.Worker,Pb=d.Blob,Qb=d.URL&&d.URL.createObjectURL,ec=d.Worker&&d.Worker.prototype.postMessage,Zb=d.parent.postMessage,ac=d.top.postMessage,Z,Ea,ma=!1,h,ya,ca="dtPC",A="dtCookie",hb="x-dtpc",ib="x-dtreferer",wa="dtLatC",P,f={},qb=!!navigator.userAgent&&0<=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("RuxitSynthetic"),D=[],fa,Pa=6E8,Ib,Ka,U,Gc={childList:!0,subtree:!0,attributes:!0,attributeOldValue:!0},Hc=["_DT_RENDERING_"],v=[],q,wc="mel",Qa="vs",Ua="rxec",ja="rxvisitid",Va,Ab=18E5,Gb=216E5,N=!1,Ra=[],Ma=!1,Ya="dt-pVO",Xa=45,Hb=!1;if(!function(a){try{h=a;var b=d.dT_;ta=d.XMLHttpRequest;ua=d.ActiveXObject;va=d.setTimeout;ab=d.setInterval;ma||(Z=d.clearTimeout,Ea=d.clearInterval);if(!((b.iCE?b.iCE():navigator.cookieEnabled)&&("complete"!==document.readyState||d.performance&&d.performance.timing)))return!1;Fc();try{La=d.localStorage,na=d.sessionStorage}catch(Ca){}Da=t();aa=[];la={};ma||(d.clearTimeout=db(Z),d.clearInterval=db(Ea),ma=!0);fa=Da%Pa+"_"+u(ba(0,1E3)+"");ya={ade:"",aew:!0,agentLocation:"",agentname:"",agentUri:"",uana:"data-dtname,data-dtName",app:"",async:!1,auto:!1,bandwidth:"300",bp1:!1,bp2:!1,bp:0===h?1:2,bs:!1,buildNumber:0,coo:!1,cooO:!1,cors:!1,csu:"",cux:!1,dataDtConfig:"",debugName:"",dASXH:0!==h,disableCookieManager:!1,disableLogging:!1,dmo:!1,dpvc:!1,disableXhrFailures:!1,domain:"",domainOverride:"",doNotDetect:"",dsndb:!1,dsss:!1,euf:!1,evl:"",extblacklist:"",exteventsoff:!1,fa:!1,featureHash:"",ffi:!1,hvt:216E5,lastModification:0,imm:!1,initializedModules:"",ign:"",instr:"",lab:!1,legacy:!1,lmut:!0,lzwd:!1,lzwe:!1,md:"",name:"",mdn:5E3,mel:200,mepp:10,moa:30,mrt:3,mpl:0===h?1024:100,msl:3E4,mhl:4E3,ncw:!1,ntd:!1,oat:180,ote:!1,perfbv:1,prfSmpl:0,pui:!1,pVO:!1,rdnt:0,reportUrl:"dynaTraceMonitor",restoreTimeline:!1,rid:"",ridPath:"",rpid:"",rt:0===h?1E4:0,rtl:0===h?0:100,rtp:0===h?2:1,rtt:1E3,rtu:200,rx_visitID:"",sl:100,sosi:!1,spc:"",srbbv:1,srbw:!0,srad:!0,srmr:100,srms:"1,1,,,",srsr:1E5,srtbv:3,srtd:1,srtr:500,srvr:"",srwo:!1,ssc:!1,st:3E3,svNB:!1,syntheticConfig:!1,tal:0,tp:"500,50,3",tt:100,tvc:3E3,uam:!1,useNewCookies:!1,uxdce:!1,uxdcw:1500,uxrgce:!0,uxrgcm:"100,25,300,3;100,25,300,3",vcfi:0===h,vs:1,WST:!1,xb:"",xmut:!0,xt:0};a:{var c=z().cfg;f={reportUrl:"dynaTraceMonitor",initializedModules:"",csu:"dtagent",dataDtConfig:"string"===typeof c?c:""};z().cfg=f;0===h&&(f.csu="ruxitagentjs");var e=f.dataDtConfig;e&&-1===p(e,"#CONFIGSTRING")&&(xa(e,f),Ga("domain"),Ga("auto"),Ga("app"),Ha(f));var k=eb("script"),g=fb(k),n=-1===p(f.dataDtConfig||"","#CONFIGSTRING")?f:null;if(0<g)for(a=0;a<g;a++)b:{var b=void 0,q=k[a],c=n;if(q.attributes){var B=f.csu+"_bootstrap.js",e=/.*\/jstag\/.*\/.*\/(.*)_bs(_dbg)?.js$/,D=c,w=q.src,v=w&&w.indexOf(B),E=q.attributes.getNamedItem("data-dtconfig");if(E){var r=w,G=E.value,x={};f.legacy=!0;if(r){var ka=/([a-zA-Z]*)[0-9]{0,4}_([a-zA-Z_0-9]*)_([0-9]+)/g.exec(r);ka&&ka.length&&(x.csu=ka[1],x.featureHash=ka[2],0===h&&(x.agentLocation=r.substr(0,p(r,ka[1])-1),x.buildNumber=ka[3]))}G&&xa(G,x,!0);pb(x.domain)||(x.domainOverride=location.hostname+","+x.domain,delete x.domain);b=x;if(!c)D=b;else if(!b.syntheticConfig){n=b;break b}}b||(b=f);if(v&&0<=v){var L=v+B.length+5;b.app=w.length>L?w.substr(L):"Default%20Application"}else if(w){var M=e.exec(w);M&&(b.app=M[1])}n=D}else n=c}if(n)for(var O in n)n.hasOwnProperty(O)&&(k=O,f[k]=n[k]);f.rx_visitID&&(z().rx_visitID=f.rx_visitID);var da=Fa();try{var T=(n=La)&&n.getItem(da);if(T){var ra=nb(T),y=xa(ra.config||""),C=f.lastModification||"0",V=u((y.lastModification||ra.lastModification||"0").substr(0,13)),ga="string"===typeof C?u(C.substr(0,13)):C;if(!C||V>=ga)if(y.agentname=ra.name,y.agentUri?Ha(y):(y.csu=ra.name,y.featureHash=ra.featureHash),Ia(y,!0),mb(y),lb(y),V>(f.lastModification||0)){var ha=m("auto"),ia=m("legacy");f=ob(y);f.auto=ha;f.legacy=ia}}}catch(Ca){}Ia(f);try{var W=f.ign;if(W&&(new RegExp(W)).test(d.location.href)){document.dT_=d.dT_=void 0;var sa=!1;break a}}catch(Ca){}f.useNewCookies&&0===h&&(ca="rxpc",A="rxsession",wa="rxlatency",hb="x-rxpc",ib="x-rxreferer");sa=!0}if(!sa)return!1;pc();try{Ib=z().disabled||!!ea("dtDisabled")}catch(Ca){}var F;if(!(F=l("agentLocation")))a:{var X=l("agentUri");if(X||document.currentScript){var H=X||document.currentScript.src;if(H){var ja=-1===p(H,"_bs")&&-1===p(H,"_bootstrap")&&-1===p(H,"_complete")?1:2,N=H.lastIndexOf("/");for(sa=0;sa<ja&&-1!==N;sa++)H=H.substr(0,N),N=H.lastIndexOf("/");F=H;break a}}var Y=location.pathname;F=Y.substr(0,Y.lastIndexOf("/"))}Ka=F;U=l("agentname")||l("csu")||(0===h?"ruxitagentjs":"dtagent");"true"===K("dtUseDebugAgent")?0>U.indexOf("dbg")&&(U=l("debugName")||U+"dbg"):U=l("name")||U;if(!m("auto")&&!m("legacy")&&!Ib){var P=l("agentUri")||Ja(l("featureHash")),Q;if(!(Q=m("async")||"complete"===document.readyState)){var R=d.navigator.userAgent,S=R.indexOf("MSIE ");Q=0<S?9>=parseInt(R.substring(S+
5,R.indexOf(".",S)),10):!1}Q?Aa(P,m("async"),void 0,void 0,"dtjsagent"):(document.write('<script id="dtjsagentdw" type="text/javascript" src="'+P+'">\x3c/script>'),document.getElementById("dtjsagentdw")||Aa(P,m("async"),void 0,void 0,"dtjsagent"))}var oa=d.location.href;0===h&&-1!==p(oa,"_DT_RENDERING_")&&(z().RMOD={conf:Gc,ignore:Hc,ID:"_DT_RENDERING_"},Ka&&Aa(Ja("R"),!0,void 0,void 0,"dtjsagent"));K(A)&&(f.cooO=!0);vc();if(0===h){var pa=!!qa(Ya);f.pVO=pa;Ba(Wa)}0===h&&J("hvt")&&(Gb=J("hvt"));za(xb,[1])}catch(Ca){return!1}return!0}(0)){try{delete d.dT_}catch(a){d.dT_=void 0}gb()&&d.console.log("JsAgent initCode initialization failed!")}}})();}).call(this);</script><script defer="defer" src="ruxitagentjs_A27SVfjqrux_10175190917092722.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest"/><link href="//i5.walmartimages.com" rel="dns-prefetch"/><script>!function(e,n,t,a,c,s,d,i,m){n.className+=" "+t,s.start=1*new Date,s.end=d=function(){n.className=n.className.replace(RegExp(" ?"+t),"")},(e[a]=e[a]||[]).hide=s,setTimeout(function(){d(),s.end=null},4e3),s.timeout=4e3}(window,document.documentElement,"async-hide","dataLayer",0,{"GTM-D8LF":!0})</script><script>!function(e,t,a,n,g){e[n]=e[n]||[],e[n].push({"gtm.start":(new Date).getTime(),event:"gtm.js"});var m=t.getElementsByTagName(a)[0],r=t.createElement(a);r.async=!0,r.src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-D8LF",m.parentNode.insertBefore(r,m)}(window,document,"script","dataLayer")</script><title>Walmart</title><script>!function(e,o){var a=-1!==(e&&e.location&&e.location.hostname||"").indexOf("bodega"),n=o.createElement("link");o.title=a?"Bodega":"Walmart",n.rel="shortcut icon",n.href=a?"/bodegafavicon.ico":"/favicon.ico",o.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(n)}(window,document)</script><link as="script" href="static/js/main.34f8c53c.js" rel="preload"/><link as="script" href="static/js/libs.789530ca.js" rel="preload"/><link as="style" href="static/css/main.34cc6bfb.css" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="crossorigin" href="static/media/myriad-pro-light.0afc5626.woff" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="crossorigin" href="static/media/myriad-pro-regular.a37eeb21.woff" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="crossorigin" href="static/media/myriad-pro-bold.5a0685ef.woff" rel="preload"/><style>.async-hide{opacity:0!important}</style><link href="static/css/main.34cc6bfb.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script src="static/js/libs.789530ca.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="static/js/main.34f8c53c.js" type="text/javascript"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: dynamically loaded page meaning additional content comes from further requests the browser makes when js runs on page. Doesn't happen with requests. You can look for the web traffic supplying this in the network tab of browser or use selenium or htmlSession

Comment: what is the p tag content you are after?

Comment: It`s the price tag from wallmart, in the us version I can retrieve it but in the mx one I can`t

Answer (score 1):

Data is dynamically retrieved from a series of API calls found in the network tab. You can make an initial request to gather the product ids and their names and then use the ids in a subsequent request to gather the price info. Store all the results in a final dictionary. You might consider using an ordered dict if order matters.

You'd probably want to re-factor this into function calls.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
#make initial request to get product ids and their associated names
data = requests.get('https://www.walmart.com.mx/api/page/search?Ntt=notebook&Nrpp=24&No=0', headers = headers).json()

#build dict of ids and names/titles to later update with info including price
d = {record['records'][0]['attributes']['productId'][0]:{'Title':record['attributes']['product.displayText']} for record in data['contents'][0]['mainArea'][1]['records']}

#build the body to send in the post request
products = [{"productId":record['records'][0]['attributes']['productId'][0],"childSkus":[record['records'][0]['attributes']['productId'][0]]} for record in data['contents'][0]['mainArea'][1]['records']]

#prepare post request to get the price info for the collected product ids
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Referer': 'https://www.walmart.com.mx/productos?Ntt=notebook'
}

data = '{"productInfos":{"products":'+ str(products) + '}}'
r = requests.post('https://www.walmart.com.mx/api/rest/model/atg/commerce/catalog/ProductCatalogActor/getProductPriceAndPromotions', headers=headers, data=data).json()

#update original dictionary with info including price for latter request using ids
for k,v in r['priceAndPromotions'].items(): 
    d[k]['info'] = v

print(d)
```

---

**Sample output:**

[image]

---

First item on visible page:

```
print(d['00019199968379'])
```